# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).steps is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, jquery-steps

So I saw really good looking forms in my bootstrap template and I wanted to use them in my project.

I placed all the required files that I think we need to import which are added at the bottom of the code, required files are in the correct directories, for example, jquery steps: `C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\public\files\bower_components\jquery.steps\js\jquery.steps.js`

'initialize-steps.js':

```js
$("#practitioner-form").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    enablePagination: true,
    autoFocus: true,
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        alert("Practitioner Added!");
    }
});
```

My HTML file with multiform (...) is skipped part:

```
<div class="card-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="practitioner-form">
                    <form method="post" id="practitioner-form" action="#">
                        <h3>Practitioner</h3>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Practitioner Information</legend>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="effective_date" class="block">{{trans('personalData.effectiveDate')}}</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input id="effective_date" name="effectiveDate" type="date" class="form-control required">
                                </div>
                            </div>

(...)


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/bower_components/jquery.steps/css/jquery.steps.css">
<!-- Required Jquery -->
<script src="/files/js/views/person/initialize-steps.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/popper.js/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Forms - Wizard js-->
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery.cookie/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery.steps/js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="/files/js/modules/practitionerCompetence.js"></script>
```

Still when I try to load up the page I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).steps is not a function` Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: change the order of loading of initialize-steps.js place it at end

Comment: you are running your code first before loading of jquery and jquery.steps it won't work

Comment: `steps` is undefined so it needs to be load before calling `$().steps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery.steps.js` is loaded way after your `initialize-steps.js`

```
<script src="/files/js/views/person/initialize-steps.js"></script>
....
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery.steps/js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
```

You need to load `initialize-steps.js` **after** it

```
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery.steps/js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<script src="/files/js/views/person/initialize-steps.js"></script>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Order js like this place your script at end

```
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/popper.js/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Forms - Wizard js-->
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery.cookie/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery.steps/js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bower_components/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="/files/js/modules/practitionerCompetence.js"></script>
<script src="/files/js/views/person/initialize-steps.js"></script>
```